# Both Javascript and Mysql calls not working on page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a really strange problem I've been trying to work around for a while now, but it's to the point where I can't anymore.

I have a simple php script. It does some api calls and pulls some data down from facebook and then displays it. For some reason on this page ANY Javascript/jquery that I put in the script just simply does not work. I insert an iframe with the javascript in the source and it works, but if the javascript is in this page it simply doesn't register. No response at all..the javascript plugin won't show up, or the function will not fire on-click.

Also MYSQL calls aren't working either. I simply get nothing back. Has this ever happened to any of you before? Any possible causes?

I don't think I have any syntax errors..I'll keep checking though. Any help is much appreciated!!

Here is the first part of my code up until the body, I can't show the rest unfortunately:

```
<?php
require 'includes/connection.php';
require 'src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => '~myid~',
'secret' => '~mysecret~',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();


// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
 try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$user_name = $user_profile[first_name];


/*
echo $user;

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo $access_token;
*/

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}/*elseif($_GET[user]){
$user = $_GET[user];

if ($user) {
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$user_name = $user_profile[first_name];


/*
echo $user;

echo "<br/><br/>";

echo $access_token;


} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}
}*/

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'offline_access'));


//Get youtube video ID from URL
// & Linkify youtube URLs which are not already links.
function linkifyYouTubeURLs($text) {
$text = preg_replace('~
    # Match non-linked youtube URL in the wild. (Rev:20111012)
    https?://         # Required scheme. Either http or https.
    (?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)? # Optional subdomain.
    (?:               # Group host alternatives.
      youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube\.com    # or youtube.com followed by
      \S*             # Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
      [^\w\-\s]       # but char before ID is non-ID char.
    )                 # End host alternatives.
    ([\w\-]{11})      # $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
    (?=[^\w\-]|$)     # Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
    (?!               # Assert URL is not pre-linked.
      [?=&+%\w]*      # Allow URL (query) remainder.
      (?:             # Group pre-linked alternatives.
        [\'"][^<>]*>  # Either inside a start tag,
      | </a>          # or inside <a> element text contents.
      )               # End recognized pre-linked alts.
    )                 # End negative lookahead assertion.
    [?=&+%\w]*        # Consume any URL (query) remainder.
    ~ix', 
    '$1',
    $text);
return $text;
}


// function to convert second to time ( minute and secong format)
function secTomin($secs)
{
$sec = $secs % 60;
if($sec < 10)
{
 $sec = '0'.$sec;
}
$min = floor($secs/60); 
$ret = $min.':'.$sec;
return $ret;
}


//Output Buffering
// make sure output buffering is off before we start it
// this will ensure same effect whether or not ob is enabled already
while (ob_get_level()) {
ob_end_flush();
}
// start output buffering
if (ob_get_length() === false) {
ob_start();
}   

//replace accents
function replaceAccentedCharacters($str)
{
$search = explode(",","ç,æ,œ,á,é,í,ó,ú,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,â,ê,î,ô,û,å,e,i,ø,u");
$replace = explode(",","c,ae,oe,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u,y,a,e,i,o,u,a,e,i,o,u");
$strreplaced = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
return $strreplaced;
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script src="togglemenu.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
SC.initialize({
client_id: "~mycliendid~",
redirect_uri: "~myurl~",
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" />  

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.multi-accordion-1.5.3.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/lionbars.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lionbars.0.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#song_list').lionbars({
           autohide: true
       });
});
</script>


</head>
```

None of the javascript in this code is working right now. Also I've replaced my app data for facebook and soundcloud in the above code. Sorry it's a little messy. Wish I could post it all but it's not up to me. Thanks for your help in advance!

Here is my SQL Statement as requested - actually just a test one I set up w/ the same format:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE fb_user_id = '$user'";

        $likes = mysql_query($query);

        $num = mysql_num_rows($likes);

        echo $num;

        while ($like_list = mysql_fetch_array($likes, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $like = $like_list['fb_from_id'];
            echo $like;

            }
```

Comment: unfortunately no I can't show you all of it, but I can show you everything I have up until the body..I'll update the post

Comment: Well, that's okay but keep in mind we can't give you a hand if there's no code to identify the error. Also, check for any errors the browser might be throwing regarding your JS.

Comment: The only time I've ever seen javascript not run is when there was an error... but that's pretty easy to check in the console.

Comment: Yea I'm not seeing any errors at all in the console..and mysql isn't working either for some reason..could output buffering be causing a problem maybe?

Comment: The body mainly consists of api calls to facebook, and they are all working, but there's one mysql call to my database that just simply doesn't work..and then same with the javascript..it's like certain requests are just shut down on this page.

Comment: Can you post the syntax you're using for your SQL query at least?

Comment: You are trying to tackle 3 possible problems at once. Debug the different levels of your app separately: 1) make sure you are getting the expected data back from your MySql query 2) make shure php renders your HTML markup as expected (view source in browser) 3) debug your javascript using the console or some more advanced tool like Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with the SQL Statement not working was that the table was named with 4 characters, as in like. When I changed it to 5, as in likes, it worked. I had no idea there was a limit on the length of a table name..someone probably would have caught that if I had posted my code. Thanks anyway for all of the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Just reading through the code you have, it looks like you might be missing your last  `ob_end_flush();`

Whenever `ob_start();` is called, it starts buffering the output and `ob_end_flush();` has to be called to output it again - so at the end of your `</head>`, try adding `ob_end_flush();`

The following code sample on `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` is from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

**Example #1 User defined callback function example**

```
<?php

function callback($buffer)
{
    // replace all the apples with oranges
    return (str_replace("apples", "oranges", $buffer));
}

ob_start("callback");

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>It's like comparing apples to oranges.</p>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

ob_end_flush();

?>
```

**The above example will output:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>It's like comparing oranges to oranges.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the ob_end_flush(); 's called after each response back from facebook in the body of my code. Sorry you couldn't see that though.